# Installing .NET framework 3.5 on windows server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, .net-framework, window, .net-3.5

I am installing .NET 3.5 framework on windows server 2012.
I downloaded dotNetFx35setup.exe from Microsoft website and copied it to a location E:\Sources\SxS.
On every link on google they are telling about this SxS folder, so did it like this.
But still I am not able to install .NET framework from GUI .
I selected .NET in features and specified the path to E:\Sources\SxS.
What I am doing wrong ??

My pc in not connected to internet, so I need some ofline installation method.

Answer (score 8):

You need your 2012/2012R2 ISO mounted or unpacked to a folder as the installation media for .net 3.5 is actually included on the DVD/ISO itself!

Next up, you can install by launching a command prompt (As Administrator) and running the following command:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:d:\sources\sxs
```

(Replacing d:\sources\sxs with C:\users\you\desktop... or wherever you unpack it to!)

The command switches used above do the following~:

```
/Online targets the operating system you're running (instead of an offline Windows image).

/Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 specifies that you want to enable the .NET Framework 3.5.

/All enables all parent features of the .NET Framework 3.5.

/LimitAccess prevents DISM from contacting Windows Update.

/Source specifies the location of the files needed to restore the feature (in this example, the D:\sources\sxs directory).
```

This works 99.9% of the time, and if it fails - it usually indicates a problem with the BITS/Windows update service - which are actually both used by the DISM (Deployment Image Servicing and Management) tool.  To fix that, take a look at [This Microsoft Fixit Article](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/971058)
.  The windows 8 manual instructiosn also work for 2012/2012R2!

Comment: The system on which I want to install .NET is on remote location(1) and the system from which I am picking ISO is on remote location(2). Now I am trying to mount ISO from location(2) to location(1) but the problem is location(1) pc is on win 2012 and location(2) pc is on win 2003 R2, so location(1) pc is not able to access shared folders of location(2) pc. So I was asking if it is necessary to use ISO only, or there is any other way which only includes small files if I manage to download and install .NET -- thxxxxxx

Comment: This didn't work for me on a naked install of 2012 R2. There are updates in kb articles that supposedly fix .NET 3.5 install (such as https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3005628) but no good for me as I wanted to do this without any updates installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need your 2012/2012R2 ISO mounted or unpacked to a folder as the installation media for .NET 3.5 is actually included on the DVD/ISO itself.

Next up, you can install by launching a Command Prompt (as an administrator) and running the following command:

```
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:Z:\sources\sxs
```

(`Z:` indicates the DVD drive)

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue with this and I have to mention that if you are using an OEM / ROHK version of Windows Server 2012 the issue could be that there is a second language pack installed.

A second language pack will also block the installation of the .NET Framework.

You can check with lpksetup.exe if there is another language installed. Remove any languages until you only have one left and then try to install the .NET Framework again.

Also if you are using OEM / ROK it could be necessary to get a different install DVD because in my case the install files for .NET were missing on the original OEM DVD.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a ISO, you can download a trial version of Windows 2012 R2, and copy/past sources/sxs, and select this location when installing the .Net using the server manager. It worked fine for me.